# How to pass multiple data from a sequelize promise to views without use inners then method

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to get data from multiple table and pass they to my view using sequelize method findAll, but to pass that data to view a need to put res.render inside a then method.
I have 5 table with no relation, so i will need to put then method one inside the other, i don't think so, there is a better way?

I need to pass data like this:

res.render('view',{
   User: users,
   Device: devices,
   Root: roots,
   Place: places,
   Why: whys
})

i try to use async and await method para i still does not get the data.

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {

    const Getuser = async () => {
        const res = await Users.findAll()
        const data = await res.json
        return data
    }

    const result = Getuser()

    console.log('dados:')

    console.log(result)


    res.render('home/index', {
        User: req.user,
        Result: result
    })
});
```

I expect that result has all data that i need to pass to my view, but the actual result is:

data:
Promise {  }

Comment: Have you tried `const result = await Getuser();` ???

Comment: ya but doesn't work, tks

Answer (score 0):

I find a better way to do this.

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {


    try {
        // pegar dados de tabela:
        // - User
        const user = await User.findAll()


        return res.render('home/index', {
            User: req.user,
            // Contact: contatos,
            // Redes: social,
            // Planos: planos
        })

    } catch(err) {
        throw new Error('Erro ao retornar usuarios')
    }


});
```

this way i can put a lot of queries here, queries belongs to multiple tables

Comment: i put async on a "callback" arrow function and await on a queries